# WSO2 - Use sequences of one project in another

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Currently we have a single monolithic WSO2 project containing all the sequences corresponding to all the pipelines that we have built. We want to break this into multiple different independent modules. For this purpose we want to create a common library project which will contain all the common sequences and other components which are shared across all these modules.

Any suggestions/ideas on how to achieve this project structure?

My WSO2 Integration Studio version is 7.1.0

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Maven Multi-Module Project in the integration studio and within this, you can create multiple projects. Within this project, you can create multiple Integration Projects to contain common artifacts and unique artifacts.

You can refer to the resources available in [1] and [2] to further clarify this. Further please refer to the article [3]. Here the Multi-Module Project is used to maintain artifacts for multiple environments by separating the artifacts into common components. You can use the same concept to separate the artifacts in your environment.

[1]-https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=058QBFbVSB8&feature=youtu.be
[2]-https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.0.0/micro-integrator/develop/create-multi-maven-project/
[3]-https://wso2.com/library/articles/2015/10/article-wso2-developer-studio-development-and-deployment-best-practices/